# What phrase to describe indefinite time in the past?

Tags: phrase-request

Suppose I need to refer something in the past by saying

> Oh, I remember you did that ___.

I remember the event in the past, however I don't remember at what time was that event happening. It could be **10 days ago**, **2 months ago**, or it happened **last year**.

Note that I remember well the event on the spot but not the time. What should I say to fill the blank in the highlighted sentence above? I don't think I'm going to use **a few days ago,** because it could be **a few months ago**.

In my country, literally we say "a few times ago" to describe indefinite time. I've looked up, but seems like there's no such thing as that phrase in English (I'm not sure if I missed something). I also think that **long time ago** is a bit too much and will sound like I remember something that happened many many years ago like telling a history.

Comment: There are many possibilities - _You've done that before_, you did that _a while ago, some time ago_...

Comment: "a few times ago" in English would be: **ages ago**. "ages ago" is indefinite.

Comment: One aspect of English usage in this area that might be confusing for learners is that in OP's context it's perfectly natural to say *Oh, I remember you **once** did that* (or *...did that **once*** - as usual, adverb position is flexible). But ***once*** in such contexts doesn't necessarily (or even *normally*) imply *on a **single** occasion* - often it just implies ***long ago*** (as in children's stories that start with ***Once** upon a time...*). Also note that *You **used to** do that* is another form of words implying ***...quite some time ago***.

Comment: "a while ago" is the most common by my knowledge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you, I would probably use "a while ago", which can cover any distance of time.

Comment: Just a note: Let's avoid using "code formatting" (in this case, enclosing text in backticks, `\``, for things that aren't code. Among other things, it can impact screen readers. I usually use either quote marks or italics to talk about words and phrases. (Note, I just used the code formatting to print the backtick itself because I am in fact talking about a code character!)

Comment: See https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4644/what-is-a-preformatted-text-for

Comment: and [Inline Code Spans should not be used for emphasis, right?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135112/295232)